# OpenGL UI library for C# with OpenTK

Tags: c#, opengl, user-interface, opentk

I'm writing a game engine in C# using OpenTK, and I'm trying to add support for UI to the engine. Writing this from scratch seems like a big headache and if someone else made a library to do it instead, that would be a lot faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although your question is poorly worded something does already exists [GWEN.NET](https://code.google.com/p/gwen-dotnet/).  The project is a direct port of the C++ GUI library of the same name.  In fact if you look in the renderers & sample there is already demos of how to integrate with OpenTK.  Should get you most of the way there.

Comment: That's what I get for writing stackoverflow questions at 3AM. Thanks for the link, looks like it's just what I need.